# how to show different alerts based on a condition after clicking a button in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I did some research before posting it here but I was not able to fix it.

In the register View I want the user to register.

I created a linked list and as user registers a username my program checks whether or not the username is already taken.

if it is taken it should give an alert saying that the username is already taken as the user clicks the register button.

if the username is not taken then it should show an alert saying the registration is successful

```
import SwiftUI

struct registerScreen: View {

    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State private var sucessfulRegister = false
    @State private var failedRegister = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            TextField()
            SecureField()
            
            Button(action: {

                let userinfo = linkedList()

                if (userinfo.contains(value: self.username)){
                    // self.failedRegister = true
                    self.failedRegister.toggle()
                    // show alert that it failed

                } else {
                    userinfo.insert(value: user(username: self.username, password: self.password))
                    // show alert that it is successfull
                    self.sucessfulRegister.toggle()

                }
            })

            {

                Text("Register")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(15.0)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to do. Though you don't need to track as many states as you are.

Firstly, you only need to track if they have failed or not. So your `failedRegister` will track if the user has successfully registered or not. That means we can get remove the `successfulRegister`.

We need a variable to track whether an alert is showing or not, for this we will use the variable `showAlert`

As you have a linked list that provides the userinfo, we will mock that with just an array containing a couple of usernames.

So here is a simplified version of your code that should work.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var names: [String] = ["John", "Mike"]
    
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password : String = ""
    @State private var failedRegister = false
    
    // this value is used for tracking whether the alert should be shown
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter username", text: $username)

            Button(action: {
                // reset to false as this is the initial state
                self.failedRegister = false
                
                if (self.names.contains(self.username)){
                    self.failedRegister.toggle()
                } else {
                    // insert the value into the user info
                }
                self.showAlert.toggle()

            }) {
                Text("Register")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(15.0)
            }
            
        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            // it would be nice to set failedRegister back to false in this function but you cannot modify state here.
            if self.failedRegister {
                return  Alert(title: Text("Failed to register"), message: Text("Unfortunately that username is taken"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            } else {
                return  Alert(title: Text("Welcome"), message: Text("You have registered"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Update using Identifiable

There is an alternative way to show different `Alerts` on the same `View`. This is to use a binding to an object that is `Identifiable`.

If we look at the ways we can initialise an `Alert` on a `View` we see there are two ways. The first has the following signature:

```
.alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> Alert)
```

Which is what is used in the example above.

However there is a second way which has the following signature:

```
.alert(item: Binding<Identifiable?>, content: (Identifiable) -> Alert)
```

This second way can allow for more complex alerts to be managed. To utilise this we need something to track the state of the alerts. We can create a simple struct that conforms to `Identifiable` and contains an enum of the different choices that we have for an alert.

We then create an `@State` variable to track the `AlertIdentifier` and initialise to `nil` so that its state is empty and will not show any alerts until it is changed.

We can then add our `.alert(item:content:)` to our `View`.

Here is a simple example showing it in action.

```
struct ContentView:View {

    private struct AlertIdentifier: Identifiable {
        var id: Choice

        enum Choice {
            case success
            case failure
        }
    }

    @State private var showAlert: AlertIdentifier? // init this as nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert = AlertIdentifier(id: .success)

            }, label: {
                Text("Show success alert")
            })

            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert = AlertIdentifier(id: .failure)

            }, label: {
                Text("Show failure alert")
            })
        }
        .alert(item: $showAlert) { alert -> Alert in

            switch alert.id {
            case .success:
                return Alert(title: Text("Success"), message: Text("You have successfully registered"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))

            case .failure:
               return Alert(title: Text("Failure"), message: Text("You have failed to register"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that in the buttons we set the `showAlert` to be an instance of the struct `AlertIdentifier` with the type of alert we want to show. In this case we have two types: success and failure (but we could have as many types as we want, and we don't need to use the names *success* and *failure*). When that is set, it will show the appropriate alert.

In our `.alert(item:content:)` we switch over the different `id`s so that we can make sure that the correct alert is shown for the correct choice.

This method is much easier than having multiple booleans, and it is easier to extend.

### Addendum for Sheets and ActionSheets

`Sheets` and `ActionSheets` are very similar to `Alerts` in how they are presented. There are four ways to present `Sheets`.

These two require a `Bool` binding:

```
.sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> View)
.sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)?, content: () -> Void)
```

These two require an `Identifiable` binding:

```
.sheet(item: Binding<Identifiable?>, content: (Identifiable) -> View)
.sheet(item: Binding<Identifiable?>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)?, content: (Identifiable) -> View)
```

For `ActionSheets` there are two ways, like `Alerts`.

With the `Bool` binding:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> ActionSheet)
```

With the `Identifiable` binding:

```
.actionSheet(item: Binding<Identifiable?>, content: (Identifiable) -> ActionSheet)
```

## Which binding should I use?

### Binding<Bool>

If you only need to show one type of `Alert`, `Sheet` or `ActionSheet` then use the `Bool` binding, it saves you having to write some extra lines of code.

### Binding<Identifiable?>

If you many different types of `Alert`s, `Sheet`s or `ActionSheet`s to show then choose the `Identifiable` binding as it makes it much easier to manage.

---

## A simpler identifiable

A simpler version of the identifiable object would be to use an enum without wrapping it in a struct. In this case we need to conform to Identifiable so we need a computed property to store the id value. We also need to make sure that the enum uses a RawRepresentable so that we can get a value for the id that is unique. I would suggest using an Int or a String. In the example below I am using an Int.

```
enum Choice: Int, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        rawValue
    }

    case success, failure
}
```

Then in the view we could do the following:

```
struct ContentView:View {

    enum Choice: Int, Identifiable {
        var id: Int {
            rawValue
        } 
        case success, failure
    }

    @State private var showAlert: Choice? // init this as nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert = .success

            }, label: {
                Text("Show success alert")
            })

            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert = .failure

            }, label: {
                Text("Show failure alert")
            })
        }
        .alert(item: $showAlert) { alert -> Alert in

            switch alert {
            case .success:
                return Alert(title: Text("Success"), message: Text("You have successfully registered"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))

            case .failure:
               return Alert(title: Text("Failure"), message: Text("You have failed to register"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I got to see other mistakes that I did through your code and now it is working quite well

Comment: Btw, this same limitation applies to sheets in macOS.

Comment: @andrew it would be nice if apple allowed complex evaluations for isPresented as such `.alert(isPresented: $failedRegister || $sucessfulRegister) `

Comment: @Learn2Code there is another way to manage multiple alerts and that is to use a `Binding<Identifiable?>` instead of a `Binding<Bool>`. I have added to my original answer showing an example of how to use it. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The same as Andrew solution, but with enum out of the scope of ContentView, which allow to use in other views, grouped in one place

```
enum Choice {
    case success
    case failure
}

extension Choice: Identifiable {
    var id: Choice { self }
}

struct ContentView:View {
    .../...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Andrew's answer is very informative here is a "long-story-short" answer, which works on **iOS14**:

```
struct YourView: View {
    enum AlertType: Identifiable {
        case first, second
        
        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }
    
    @State var alertType: AlertType?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show alert #1") {
                alertType = .first
            }
            
            Button("Show alert #2") {
                alertType = .second
            }
        }
        .alert(item: $alertType) { type in
            switch type {
            case .first:
                return Alert(title: Text("First alert"))
            case .second:
                return Alert(title: Text("Second alert"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```